# Collection view delegate not getting called on button click and hiding button on collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**Question 1:**

I have a collection view and every item on collection view has a button and a label. When I click on the label, collection view delegate's function 'didSelectItemAt' does get called. However when I click on the button, 'didSelectItemAt' does not get called.

To fix this, I removed the touch-up inside action I had set on the button, but that didn't help either. How do I get 'didSelectItemAt' of collection view to be called when button is clicked?

**Question 2:**

For the same button described in Question 1, there are cases where I only want to show the label and not the button. However when I hide the button, it still takes up the space on the view. How can I hide the button such that it doesn't consume the space? Below is what I tried:

```
collectionViewCell.button.isHidden = true
collectionViewCell.button.alpha = 0
collectionViewCell.button.imageView?.alpha = 0
```

Comment: Does the button need to also do something else in addition to `didSelectItemAt`?  If not, then don't use a button, use an image view or a label that looks like a button.  Otherwise you have to pass the touch event through, and there are a lot of answers on this site on how to do that.  For question 2, if you're able to, just use a stack view and then set the button view's isHidden to true when you want to hide it.  The stack view will reclaim the space like you want, making it seem like the button isn't there at all.

Comment: You shouldn’t call didSelect on button taps, it’s meant to be called on cell selection. You should declare your own function that should be invoked on button tap. Button hiding wouldn’t change button width, you need to change width constraint.

Comment: @TusharSharma but what if each button is unique?  So if your press the button on cell 1 it does something different than on cell 2?  How do you distinguish WHICH button was pressed?  I would think you need a combination of didSelectItemAt AND the button press (so pressing other parts of the cell doesn't result in the action the button relegates).  So the question is still valid, and yet no one has tackled it in a year.